# How to config htpasswd with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

i want to make some pages password protected using .htpasswd

How can i do it ??

```
# Do the regex check against the URI here, if match, set the "require_auth" var
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/product-category/ require_auth=true

# Auth stuff
AuthUserFile /home1/thetimh6/public_html/htpasswd
AuthName "Password Protected"
AuthType Basic

# Setup a deny/allow
Order Deny,Allow
# Deny from everyone
Deny from all
# except if either of these are satisfied
Satisfy any
# 1. a valid authenticated user
Require valid-user
# or 2. the "require_auth" var is NOT set
Allow from env=!require_auth
```

I am try it in my htaccess file but it is showing me

500 Server Error

Comment: You should never put the .htpasswd file in public_html!!!

Comment: Can you please give me a code how to use .htpasswd ??

Comment: please see below.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the following code in .htaccess in public_html

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Then create a .htpasswd, but put it OUTSIDE public_html

So the /path/to/.htpasswd is pointing to that location

Answer (score -1):

It's quite possible I'm thinking too simple here, but shouldn't the code:

```
AuthUserFile /home1/thetimh6/public_html/htpasswd
```

be:

```
AuthUserFile /home1/thetimh6/public_html/.htpasswd
```

Comment: No not working You can check here https://www.thetimelesspearlwholesale.com/product-category/earrings, username and password is admin